# Importing specific function from a module to another in Python3.3

Tags: python, tkinter, python-import

I've a module named A.py like

```
from tkinter import *

def puppa():
    print("something")
a=Tk()
print("someone")
```

i would import ONLY the function puppa in a new module, but if i perform

```
from A import puppa
```

it imports also the tkinter window and prints "someone"... how do i make it work?
thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is because even though you import only `puppa` from `A` it still initializes the whole `A.py` file and as a result runs:

```
a=Tk()
print("someone")
```

Instead, you should put these all such external lines of code either into methods or a `main()` function in your `A.py` file. This is to ensure that you only run what you want to run.

If for some reason you want `A.py` to run the above script when it is run independently, you can put all the main script in a `main` function and then add this piece of code to the end of your `A.py` script:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```